# Why shouldn't use Linq in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Somewhere I had to use a linq statement for select a result set from my Model that Controller returned in Index ActionResult.
for doing this, I googled "how to use linq in view razor" and I get the result and my application worked properly, but I see some recommendation that say "Don't use Linq in view".
Why we shouldn't use it however it's possible?
And if I don't want using it what's the solution?

This is my query :

```
 @using System.Linq
 @{var lst = (from x in item.Showtimes select x.ShowtimeDate).Distinct();}
 @foreach (var showTimeItem in lst)
    {
      <option value="@showTimeItem">@showTimeItem</option>   
    }
```

**UPDATE**

This is my controller Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MelliConcert.Models.MelliConcertEntities db = new  Models.MelliConcertEntities();
            var listOfConcerts = (from x in db.Concert
                                  orderby x.ID ascending
                                  select x).Take(15).ToList();
            return View(listOfConcerts);
        }
```

And i use it in the view like this :

```
@model IEnumerable<MelliConcert.Models.Concert>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
               @if (item.OpenedForFirst == true)
               { 
                   //... 
               }
               //Some Codes
               @using System.Linq
               @{var lst = (from x in item.Showtimes select x.ShowtimeDate).Distinct();}
               @foreach (var showTimeItem in lst)
               {
                 <option value="@showTimeItem">@showTimeItem</option>   
               }
            }
```

My linq statement placed in this loop.
What should i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with using LINQ in a view *per se*.  The problem isn't that you're using LINQ, the problem is that you're doing this:

```
@{var lst = (from x in item.Showtimes select x.ShowtimeDate).Distinct();}
```

Any time you have to declare and set a variable inside your view, that's probably an indication that you need to modify your model.  Your view model should have a property on it for this purpose.  Something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeType> DistinctShowtimes
{
    get
    {
        return (from x in item.Showtimes select x.ShowtimeDate).Distinct();
    }
}
```

Then the point about LINQ in the view becomes moot, as all you'd need is this:

```
@foreach (var showTimeItem in Model.DistinctShowtimes)
{
    <option value="@showTimeItem">@showTimeItem</option>   
}
```

**UPDATE (in response to your updated question):**

Now the problem (albeit slightly less of one) is this:

```
@model IEnumerable<MelliConcert.Models.Concert>
```

While this works fine, it's limiting.  And what you're experiencing is that limitation.  You're asking yourself, "How do I return more than one thing to the view?"  The answer is to create a custom view model for that view.  Right now your view is binding to an enumeration of `Concert` objects.  Which is fine, if that's all it needs.  But it turns out that's not all it needs.  It has some custom logic that requires a little more.  So, you create a custom view model.  Something like this:

```
public class ConcertsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Concert> Concerts { get; set; }
    // other properties, methods, anything
}
```

Then in your controller action, you return one of those instead:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using(var db = new  Models.MelliConcertEntities())
    {
        var concertsModel = new ConcertsModel();
        concertsModel.Concerts = (from x in db.Concert
                                  orderby x.ID ascending
                                  select x).Take(15).ToList();
        return View(concertsModel);
    }
}
```

(Note also the use of the `using` statement, which should always be employed when making use of `IDisposable` resources.)

So now your view is still getting the list of `Concert` objects, but it's packaged in a custom view model onto which you can add any more functionality you need for that view.  Next, in your view, change the model declaration:

```
@model MelliConcert.Models.ConcertsViewModel
```

(This assumes you put it in the `Models` namespace.  Depending on the scale of your application, you might want to break out view models into their own namespace.  I don't often use the `Models` namespace in the actual application for core business objects, so our projects are likely structured very differently.  This should get you going, but you'll want to make sure you keep your concerns cleanly separated.)

Then in the view code you can reference what you need from that object.  So if you need to access the list, instead of just calling something like `@foreach (var item in model)` you would call `@foreach (var item in model.Concerts)`.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer,i update my question for describing problem better, please read it.i don't know how i use your solution in my problem.

Comment: @samangholami: I've updated my answer accordingly.  Essentially what you're doing is taking a step into deeper object oriented programming, which is a good thing.  This is simply a case where you need to make a custom object because you're looking at a set of functionality which can be encapsulated into its own concern (populating the view with data).

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case the argument would be to do the maximum amount of processing on your model before returning it to the view.

So why not return distinct showtimes to the view and then just loop through them?

The only problem with your current set up is it may undermine the spirit of MVC which was to separate concerns.  The view shouldn't be applying any logic that needs to be tested (or as little as possible).  By keeping logic in the models and controllers you make unit testing easier and the views are simpler for a developer to read.

**EDIT**
Hey @[samangholami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2486709/saman-gholami), you can return multiple objects to a view using a class.  Create a class called "PAGENAMEViewModel" or something similar and create a property for every value you want to return.  For example:

```
public class MovieViewModel
{
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Actors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ShowTimeRecord> Showtimes { get; set; }


    public class ShowTimeRecord
    {
        public string TheaterName { get; set; }
        public string TheaterAddress { get; set; }
        public DateTime ShowtimeDate{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then return your complex model like so:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    MovieViewModel model = myMovieHelper.GetMovieData();

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.because i used 'item' another places.

Comment: Yes,you right,but how i can return multiple result with a ActionResult in Controller?

Comment: Ok,this solution sounds good but i don't know how can i use i with out using linq yet...

Answer (score 1):

Besides the possible separation of concerns problem you also might have a performance problem that can be more difficult to diagnose.

If your LINQ query is somehow connected to the database via some ORM or something like that by looping through the results you might create a N+1 problematic scenario.

Moving it off the view might not prevent it, but at least puts it into somewhere that is more visible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because it's not respecting the **separation of concerns** principle, which is a fundamental concept of MVC. By performing *that* query in the view, you're taking business logic to it.

It has nothing to do with Linq itself. You could, for example, have a Linq statement to perform an `OrderBy`. That's ok because it's not business logic, it's a proper view operation (to order data into a table, let's say).